# Regex query to print required output

Tags: regex, bash, unix, scripting, grep

I have the following input

ASR **cAND** text1 **(p**.Pro221Leu)
   GMPPB **cAND** text2 **c**.1069G>A (p.Val357Ile)
   KLHL40 **cAND** text3
   GMPPB **cAND** text4 **c**.220C>T (p.Arg74Ter)

I want to print any text between bold ie between the words **cAND** and (**(p** or **c**)
   Note: text3 is not expected since it fails to satisfy above condition.

```
expected output(underlined) 
text1
text2
text4    

regex used
grep "cAND.+(c\.|\(p)"
```

However I am not getting the expected output. Please tell me what is wrong in my Regex ?thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With grep in Perl mode, you can do this (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dQ6rR1)):

```
grep -P "cAND[ ]*\K\S+(?=[ ]*(?:c.|\(p))" some_path_or_files
```

**How does it work? Greed.**

- The `cAND[ ]*` ensures we have the `cAND` and also matches the following spaces
- The `\K` discards what we have matched so far, so that we can return clean strings such as `text1`
- The `\S+` matches the characters we want: any non-space character
- The `(?=[ ]*(?:c.|\(p))` lookahead ensures that what follows is spaces and the c or p delimiter

**What was wrong?**

1. The `.+` in your `cAND.+(c\.|\(p)` is "greedy": it eats up all the characters until the end of the string, then it backtracks until the `(c\.|\(p)` can be met. Therefore, it eats characters up to the last c or p, for instance: `cAND text2 c.1069G>A (p`
2. It was matching the whole string, not just `text1` as you wanted.

**Alternate Regex with Lookarounds**

Since you're studying regex... This also works.

```
(?<=cAND).*?(?=c.|\(p)
```

**Reference**

[The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)

Comment: What's the expansion for FYI?

Comment: @AvinashRaj FYI, the expansion for FYI is "for your information". :)

Comment: FYI Added explanation of what was wrong with your pattern. :)

Comment: @user1377135 You've very welcome, see you next time. :)

Comment: But your first command displays `text1,2,3,4`. op wants only `text1,2,4`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed -r`:

```
sed -r 's/^.*cAND ([^ ]+)( \(?[cp].*)?$/\1/' file
text1
text2
text3
text4
```

**PS:** Use `sed -E` on OSX.

Comment: op wants the output to be `text1,2,4`

Answer (score 0):

And the one through awk,

```
$ awk '$2=="cAND" && $4~/^c|^\(p/ { print $3}' file
text1
text2
text4
```

Checks for the column2 to be `cAND` and also the column 4 to be starts with `c` or `(p`. If both conditions are satisfied, column 3 for that corresponding line would be printed.